# defun to replace regex pattern with original pattern plus new line

Tags: commands, interactive

I have written the following lisp code to search for a regex pattern and append new line to it:

```
(defun readmode ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char 1)
  (while (search-forward-regex "\(</[a-z]+>\)" nil t) (replace-match "\1C-q C-j" t nil)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-m") 'readmode)
```

When I run, I am getting error:

> command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, readmode

```
Input text:
<pre> Line 1 </pre> <p> Line 2 </p>

Expected text:
<pre> Line 1 </pre>
<p> Line 2 </p>
```

Comment: `Wrong type argument: commandp, readmode` suggests that you initially wrote and evaluated the function definition *without* the `(interactive)` declaration, and have not then re-evaluated it since adding it.

Comment: You also have a typo, as `search-forward-regexp` has that trailing `p`.  Note that's an alias for `re-search-forward` (which is the more common form).

Comment: I corrected the typo, executed it by C-x C-e and restarted emacs and now when I run nothing is happening. In the *Messages* buffer, I see nothing.

Comment: The question should now be closed as unclear. You posed a question. It was answered in a comment. You posed another question in a comment, etc. That's not how this site works. The question could be kept open if the answer in a comment were moved to an answer (missing `interactive` spec). But in that case the question is a duplicate.

Comment: The regex is wrong as to both usages:  As to the first, you need two (2) backslashes in front of each parenthesis.  As to the second, a new line is specified with a single backslash followed by a lowercase n; i.e.,  `\n` -- we do not use a keyboard shortcut spelled out here.  As to `replace-match`, I was unable to figure how to use the `\N`, in this case `\1` .... to get it work -- `(concat (match-string 1) "\n")`.  And, further, I had to modify your first regex to add a `\s` outside of the grouping because there is *a space* between `</pre> <p>` which needs to be eliminated programmatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot @lawlist !!! it worked..

Comment: @phils thank you too!!